# FadeIn Script Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function () {
    $j('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function () { //Step 1
        $j("#sp-container").fadeIn("fast", function () { //Step 2
            $j("#content-wrap").delay(9000).fadeIn("slow"); //Step 3
        });
    });
});
```

The script works fine until step 3. Step 3 does not fade in the div as it is supposed too. Why is this script not working and how do I fix it?

What I am excepting:

Step 1: Content on Page Loads then Script Fires

Step 2: I have a splash screen that runs for approximately 9 seconds.

Step 3: After animation content-wrap div fades in.

***HTML:***

```
<div id="loading"> 
  <!-- CONTENT --> 
</div>

<div id="sp-container">
  <!-- CONTENT --> 
</div>

<div id="content-wrap">
  <!-- CONTENT --> 
</div>
```

Note: Before I added the splash animation my JS looked like this which worked without issue:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(window).load(function() {
  $j('#loading').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $j("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow");    
      });
    });
```

[Here is a link to the page in question.](http://www.ubhape2.com/testing/)

Comment: What exactly where you expecting ?

Comment: Code works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/YZyHy/ I just changed the delay so I did not have to sit there for a year. Maybe something else has set the display to hidden that wraps the content? Maybe a missing closing tag/duplicate ids?

Comment: @epascarello - I was looking at my code and realized that I did not have `sp-container` with `display:none;` when I added that into the CSS it also quit fading in!

Comment: Then provide us with an actual demonstration of the problem.  As it stands, [the code you've shown us is working](http://jsfiddle.net/YZyHy/).

Comment: @Sparky672 - Added a link to the page in question.

Comment: @epascarello - Added link to page since code provided is working.

Comment: The `.sp-container` is set to 100% height and appears to be covering everything else according to my console.  You don't have a JavaScript issue... you have an HTML/CSS issue.  In your OP, these are `id`'s and in your demo page these are `class`'s.  This discrepancy is just confusing to people trying to help.

Comment: The JavaScript on your page is looking for `#sp-container` but your container is using `class`, not `id`.  Should be `.sp-container`, I guess.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I feel like an idiot. I was working with the code and had changed it to id vs class on one page but I copied the wrong code and it was class! When I changed the Script to class it works. My apologies. Post your last couple comments as an answer and I will give you credit. Thanks

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [demo page](http://www.ubhape2.com/testing/)  and your OP contain different code.

The JavaScript on [your demo page](http://www.ubhape2.com/testing/) is looking for `#sp-container` but your container is using `class`, not `id`.  Should be `.sp-container`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout()` instead of delay, and wrapping that last 9000ms delayed animation in it.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9mfTW/1/)

```
$('#loading').fadeOut('fast', function () { //Step 1
    $("#sp-container").fadeIn("fast", function () { //Step 2            
        setTimeout(function () { $("#content-wrap").fadeIn("slow"); }, 9000); //Step 3
    });
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually [load-event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) docs says this works, haha, learning experience :)

I think you are mistaking the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) functions with the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

switch:

```
$j(window).load(function() {
```

to

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: load waits til everything is loaded, ready does not. Your answer will do nothing here to solve the problem. It will also will start running before images are loaded.

Comment: that is news to me > http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ never read that before, thank you.